# Trying to create guide that pull information from database according to interests etc the user has input

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net, algorithm, visual-studio

Hi I was wondering would anyone please be able to help me, I'm creating a travel website in Visual Studio using ASP.NET that generates a unique travel guide for the user using the information they have submitted according to their interests, how their travelling, where their travelling. But I'm unsure how to pull the information from the MySQL table according to what they've input to only show relevant information to them. Could someone please help, i'm not the best at coding and sorry if its really simple.

Thanks

Comment: Do some research, you'll find out far more on the internet than we can explain to you.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any suggestions on what to initially look into please @David

Comment: "MySQL SELECT query" if you've got no idea how to do it